# What firmware to choose for ASUS WL-500GP v1

Tags: router, firmware, openwrt

I've found several firmwares out there: OpenWRT, DD-WRT, Tomato and [Oleg's](http://oleg.wl500g.info/). I'm wondering what is the best choice?

Router is working in the home network (desktop through wires, laptop uses WiFi). Also I plan to run torrent and VPN client on it.

Comment: Belongs on superuser

Comment: Note that there's an issue with some ASUS routers that can brick them on custom firmware install. Beware!

Answer (score 2):

OpenWRT.org
This is definitely something where everyone will just recommend whichever one they're familiar with. But please note that most of these are based on openwrt, and largely the forks were created because at that time openwrt did not have a very good web interface. These days openwrt does have a good web interface, and I highly recommend it.

See [this example](http://jasonschaefer.com/?p=3) of how openwrt makes everything easy :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had no problem with Tomato.  I don't run any services on it, but I don't see any reason you couldn't.  There is command-line access; there are startup scripts; there is SMB mounting; there is a flash filesystem.

I don't know if you already have a device, but make sure that the software you choose supports the hardware you have or are going to get.

Comment: There is an info in Tomato web site that it does not support USB for ASUS WL-500GP

Answer (score 0):

I have Asus WL-500g and I use DD-WRT. I currently have v24 SP1 installed and there are no issues with it.

I find it really easy to configure and it supports Asus hardware quite well. Torrenting from it is little bit harder with DD-WRT, but there is support for installing additional packages.

VPN is supported just fine.